# Tiered selection of location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

First of all, what I am trying to do is allow the user to narrow down their location using a database of countries, counties, towns and cities.

It's too much to show them every city in one go so I want them to narrow down their filter.

Ebay does this with their categories:

[image]

I was going to implement it something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/z8qbn6zw/3/

```
 <select>
    <option selected disabled>Choose country</option>
    <option value="volvo">England</option>
    <option value="saab">Wales</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Ireland</option>
    <option value="audi">Scotland</option>
</select>
<select class="hidden">
    <option selected disabled>Choose State</option>
    <option value="volvo">Avon</option>
    <option value="volvo">London</option>
    <option value="saab">Kent</option>
</select>
<select class="hidden">
    <option selected disabled>Choose City</option>
    <option value="volvo">Town A</option>
    <option value="saab">Town B</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Town C</option>
    <option value="audi">Town D</option>
</select>
```

I'm a bit stuck because this is going to be part of a larger form, and sometimes the user will not have javascript enabled.

**Question 1:** What HTML markup is the best way to approach this, should I be using selects, or instead have each item as a submit button with that location value.

**Question 2:** How should I approach the fact that the user may not have javascript enabled and that this will be part of a much larger form.

Any input and advice from someone who has attempted this before would be appreciated.

Comment: Really, how many people do you know who disable javascript in their browser? But if that is really important, if you switch to `<input type="radio"...` you can do it in css using the [checked](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/) selector.

Comment: Just so I understand, what advantage does that have over the select?

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this to work without javascript, you can do it like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="rgroup" id="sel1">Selection 1</input>
...

<div id="cont1" class="container">
    <input type="radio">Something 1</input>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: none;
}

#sel1:checked ~ #cont1 {
    display: block;
}
...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gp8kubu/)

If you use `<select>` and `<option>`, you can't do this because the `<option>`s cannot select the `<div>`s which would have to be outside the `<select>`.